# What does a proof going to the right/left mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I was watching a video about the Euclidean Algorithm and how to prove it, and they mentioned proofs going to the right and left. What does this mean?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: If you have a theorem: $p$ if and only if $q$, the proof going from left to right is given $p$, we have to prove $q$. Conversely, the proof going from right to left is given $q$, we have to prove $p$.

Comment: It would be good to link to the specific video and (better still) the part of the video that uses this phrase."Going to the right/left" is not a formal mathematical term (it's likely used to make the flow of logic feel more intuitive), so some more specific context would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example.

According to Pythagoras theorem, we have that:

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle. Then, $AB^2 = BC^2 + AC^2$ if and only if $ABC$ is rectangle in $C$.

To prove this theorem from left to right would be to assume "$AB^2 = BC^2 + AC^2$" as a hypothesis and "$ABC$ is rectangle in $C$" as conclusion. So you'd try to develop the conclusion from the hypothesis.

Analogically, to prove it from right to left would be to assume "$ABC$ is rectangle in $C$" as a hypothesis and "$AB^2 = BC^2 + AC^2$" as a conclusion.